# zend framework 1.11.11 routing

Tags: zend-framework, routes

http://xxxxxx.xxx/man/pant/man-yellow-box-pant

```
$router = $ctrl->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default
$router->addRoute(
    'location',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':category/:subcategory/:productname',
        array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'product',
            'action' => 'index',
            'id' => 'id',
            'name' => 'p_name'

        )
    )
);
```

above this code is not working..

```
$routers = $ctrl->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default
$routers->addRoute(
    'location',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':uname',
        array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action' => 'index',
            'id' => 'uid',
            'name' => 'u_name'

        )
    )
);
```

above is working...........

please suggest me why not working when both code write on same page, same project..

Answer (score 1):

Your routes need to have a unique name. By calling them both 'location', the second one you add replaces the first.

Comment: i have 5 module and 15 controller with 78 function and need to all url make to SEO friendly so i did, if i change to location with username, he not working,and $router = $ctrl->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default
$router->addRoute(
    'category',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':category/:subcategory/:productname',
        array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'product',
            'action' => 'index',
            'id' => 'id',
            'name' => 'p_name'

        )
    )
);  category and subcategory system is not working..

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you're using now, along with an example URL you're testing with, and info on what exactly isn't working (is it matching the wrong route or 404'ing?)

Answer (score 0):

I know writing mistake, if we change location to other then also not working because i have more URL condition and condition is we not use on module/controller/function name on URL, according to category or function we use to name On URL.

I have 4 module and 15 controller with as per more function and need to all URL make to SEO friendly so i did, if i change to location with username, he not working,and

$routers = $ctrl->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default
$routers->addRoute('category',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':category/:subcategory/:productname',
        array(
            'module' => 'default',
            'controller' => 'product',
            'action' => 'index',
            'id' => 'id',
            'name' => 'p_name')));

Category and Subcategory system is not working.

how to set right path way as per my condition and not through 404 error

URL get Like http://testing.com/man/pant/man-yellow-box-pant